# How to make drag-able WPF window without default windows style?

Tags: wpf

I was making a WPF application with Windows style = None, I managed to create and work exit button in my window but i don't know how to make it drag able while pressing left mouse button.
I have created Mouse left button down event in .cs file as below:

```
private void see(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   this.DragMove();
}
```

Then I added border in .xaml file to do dragging of the window as below:

```
<Grid>
   <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Height="120" Width="100" MouseLeftButtonDown="see" />
</Grid>
```

Now i don't understand what is the problem here? I will be very thankful if someone help me in this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a similar pattern to this Window:

```
public class DragableWindowNoStyle : Window
{

    public DragableWindowNoStyle()
    {
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        Grid grid = new Grid() { };
        _moveBorder = new Border()
        {
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Red,
            Background = Brushes.Black,
            Width = 50,
            Height = 20,
            HorizontalAlignment= System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top,
        }; 
        grid.Children.Add(_moveBorder); 
        this.Content = grid;

        _moveBorder.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += _moveBorder_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;  
    }

    Point _startPoint;
    bool _isDragging = false;
    Border _moveBorder;

    private void _moveBorder_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.Capture(this))
        {
            _isDragging = true;
            _startPoint = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDragging)
        {
            Point newPoint = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
            int diffX = (int)(newPoint.X - _startPoint.X);
            int diffY = (int)(newPoint.Y - _startPoint.Y);
            if (Math.Abs(diffX) > 1 || Math.Abs(diffY) > 1)
            {
                Left += diffX;
                Top += diffY;
                InvalidateVisual();
                _startPoint = newPoint;
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDragging)
        {
            _isDragging = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null);
        }
    } 



}
```

Comment: Please note that I edited the code and used [``PointToScreen``](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346961.aspx).

Comment: no, its not working, shows no errors or warning just it is not working, should i send my project to you?

Comment: @Jimmy Those aren't events he added to the border but that are overriden on the window class, you don't need those events on border, remove all that and just use the code Inside of your window class.

Comment: @jimmy Copy the provided code. Use this code ``DragableWindowNoStyle win = new DragableWindowNoStyle(); 
            win.Show();`` to show an instance of this window. You can move the window by clicking and dragging. Anything more than this, you might need to set the style and template of the Window. I just wanted to point you to the right direction. Hope it was a help.

Comment: ok sorry for misunderstanding, I got it now, its all working with your code but i want to do this with a border? so what i will be needed to do that?

Comment: thank you very much, it is working now as i wanted. But there is only one problem left, can't it be more simple? this code is very complex, can you manage to do all this just by 'DragMove'?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think all approaches are similar to this one. Of course, if you study it, you will see that it is not that much difficult.

Comment: ok thank you. Now I am trying to do this in user control but it is not happening, so how i can achieve this with user control?

Comment: Ask a new question. Write the problem in details and give a reference to this question and you might get more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to create a custom window with resize, drag, minimize, restore and close functionality from scratch available here:

**How to create a custom window in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

You could also customize a window while retaining its standard functionality using the `WindowChrome` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx. Then you don't have to implement the resize and drag functionality yourself.